# Label every repeat of a factor as the same number in a new column in order of occurence across factor levels

Tags: r, count, duplicates, unique

I have a data frame with a factor column, "class", in which some factor levels are repeated. There is another factor column, "set" with multiple levels.  I would like to create a new column that adds the count of unique values from the "class" column, restarting the count for each level of "set", while retaining the order of occurrence from the original list for each value of "set". This new column would just have duplicate count values every time that factor level occurred again. Example data below:

```
a <- data.frame(c(rep(LETTERS[1:3],2),LETTERS[6:8],LETTERS[1:2]),rep(set_a,11),rep(NA,11))
b <- data.frame(c(LETTERS[11:16],LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[11:13]), rep(set_b,12),rep(NA,12))
colnames(a) <- c(class,set,count)
colnames(b) <- c(class,set,count)
c <- rbind(a,b)
c$class <- as.factor(c$class)
c$set <- as.factor(c$set)
```

For the above data my ideal output would be the below:

```
class   set count
A   set_a   1
B   set_a   2
C   set_a   3
A   set_a   1
B   set_a   2
C   set_a   3
F   set_a   4
G   set_a   5
H   set_a   6
A   set_a   1
B   set_a   2
K   set_b   1
L   set_b   2
M   set_b   3
N   set_b   4
O   set_b   5
P   set_b   6
A   set_b   7
B   set_b   8
C   set_b   9
K   set_b   1
L   set_b   2
M   set_b   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you create the c data frame without the "count" column already in it you can do the following with dplyr:

```
makecounter <- c %>% group_by(class, set) %>%
     filter(row_number() == 1)%>%
     ungroup%>%
     group_by(set)%>%mutate(count = seq_along(set))

final <- left_join(c, makecounter, by = c("class","set"))
```

Comment: You are both correct and awesome simiultaneously. The "seq_along" function was the key I was missing. Thanks so much for your help!